# routing a request in node.js with express

Tags: express

I have generated a sample app using express generator and inside app.js there is

> var routes = require('./routes/index');
>
> var users = require('./routes/users');

There are two files generated index.js and users.js

To use the code inside the files there are this lines

> app.use('/', routes);
>
> app.use('/users', users);

My question,is ***app.use('/', routes)*** handles every request that is on a route starting with ***'/'***, then how will a request to a route to ***'/users'*** will be routed to ***users*** route

Comment: `app.use('/', routes);` match only the root calls (not the ones that starts with)

Comment: Assuming, `routes` and `users` are routers, a router that does not have a route for a specific URL will pass control onto the next handler in the chain so it will get a chance to examine the URL and let one of its route handlers run.

Comment: you should call app.use('/user',users) first after that you should call app.use('/',routes)

Answer (score 0):

`app.use()` is middleware. You pass it an optional path and a function and it is the function's job to decide if it wants to pass the request on to further middleware or further routes. It does that by calling `next()` or if it doesn't want to pass it on, it doesn't call next().

So, if you have:

```
app.use("/", fn);
```

That middleware will get called for all paths, but the code inside the function you pass it decides whether to pass the request on or not.